# Form validation multidimensional select boxes

Tags: javascript, validation

This is the screenshot of the work.

The Colors dropdown have sub colors. Now the name of colors is `color[]`. For this case you can see that there are 3 colors. 1st color have 1 sub color, 2nd color have 3 sub colors and color 3 have 1 sub color

[image]

There are numbers of validations which I need to check.

1. Any color, sub color should not be 'SELECT' (in image all dropdowns
   are selected for colors)
2. The parent percentages (1st color is missing percentage box in image, but is on site) of all 3 colors should be exactly 100
3. Sub percentages for each color also should be exact 100%, for example color 2 have 3 sub colors and 3 colors have 20, 40, 40 as sub percentages

I am having trouble validating the form in JS.

I have tried `frm["color[]"].length` and it give me three, now first color's sub colors are having `color[1][]` name. If I get the length of `color[]` and loop on it.

```
for (i = 0; i < frm["color[]"].length; i++){
    k = i+1;
    console.log( frm["color["+k+"][]"] ); 
}
```

it work.

As right now there are 3 colors and  `console.log(frm["color[]"].length)` return 3, if there is only 1 color, it will return me number of items in the dropdown, which are like 2k+

If you have any question please let me know jQuery solutions are also welcome

Thank you

Comment: Jquery: `$('select[name^="color["]')` should select all selects beginning with color[

Comment: it selected, but how can i loop over each select and check its value, that a user selected one or not. And i want to know the index so I can alert user that 'COLOR 3 is not selected'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery:

```
$('select[name^="color["]').each(function() {
  if ($(this).val()=="SELECT") {
    alert(this.name.replace(/[^color0-9]/gi," ")+"is not selected");
    return false;
  }
});
```