# Javascript select array length

Tags: javascript, validation

I had posted a long question here [Form validation multidimensional select boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995314/form-validation-multidimensional-objects/14995478#14995478)

a short problem is, I am allowing users to add multiple rows for data input. Each row have

```
<select name="color[]">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
   <option>4</option>
</select>
```

If there are 3 select boxes i can get its length by using `frm["color[]"].length` and it will return 3.

But if there is only 1 select box `frm["color[]"]` will return me number of options from the select and return me 4

**EDIT**

used `document.getElementsByName("color[]")` and it worked. Thank you kolink,

```
    colors= document.getElementsByName("colors[]").length;

    console.log(colors); // print proper numbers now
    for(i=0; i<colors; i++){
        dd = frm["colors["+i+"]"].value; // <- how to check value
        console.log(dd);
        k = i+1;
        var subColors = document.getElementsByName("colors["+k+"][]").length

    }
```

How i can get the value of selected option from select box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the more specific `frm.getElementsByName("color[]")`, this will explicitly select the `<select>` elements instead of what it currently does.

EDIT: Here's how to use it:

```
var sels = document.getElementsByName("colors[]"), l = sels.length, dd;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    dd = sels[i];
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: used `document.getElementsByName("color[]")` and it worked. But how can i get its selected value in a loop. I want to loop on all select boxes to get values